# Is window.localAudio a thing?

Tags: javascript, microphone

I found Mozilla's [Getting browser microphone permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Build_a_phone_with_peerjs/Connect_peers/Get_microphone_permission). It defines a function to request permission and listen to client's microphone as such:

```js
function getLocalStream() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true}).then( stream => {
        window.localStream = stream; // A
        window.localAudio.srcObject = stream; // B
        window.localAudio.autoplay = true; // C
    }).catch( err => {
        console.log("u got an error:" + err)
    });
}
```

I checked in Chrome, Firefox and Safari - all of them throw an error about `window.localAudio` being `undefined`. Where did this tutorial get it from? Was `window.localAudio` ever a thing? What was it supposed to do?

Comment: tell what you whant to achive

Comment: @Robert The question is about where `window.localAudio` is defined, since it’s used in this tutorial.

Comment: It looks like this code originally comes from [this Medium blog post](//medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/building-an-internet-connected-phone-with-peerjs-775bd6ffebec), which actually goes on to explain the code. I assume, it’s something PeerJS-specific.

Comment: If you read the text it tells you want it is `window.localAudio` is the id of the audio element on the page. *window.localAudio.srcObject = stream sets the <audio> element with the ID of localAudio's src attribute to be the MediaStreamreturned by the promise so that it will play our stream.* Tutorial uses bad practices to reference element via their id without getElementById or querySelector

Comment: yeap. but if he whant just pipe strem to speakers he need create audio context and set this as buffer source.

Comment: Aha! _“in our HTML, we have an audio element with the ID `localAudio`”_. This uses the very bad practice of relying on this behavior: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](/q/3434278/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon oh damn! That's some really poor wording from Mozilla, this blog post you found explains it better. I'm not sure if I agree with this question being a duplicate though.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate either. Yes the linked question takes part in solving this one, but it is not the actual problem.

Comment: @MauriceNino yeah, exactly. But it's not the first time someone on SO does that this way. Like the "duplicated" post is the answer, but not the question :D

Comment: @MauriceNino it's like making a question "How much is 2 + 2?" a duplicate of "How much is 1 + 3?".

Comment: Yep, sad to see that people with enough points, can just do whatever they want on here. The only thing you can do is flag this as "In need of moderator intervention", or get enough people to Vote-reopen this question.

Comment: Yeah, even I think that duplicate closure is really a stretch. Voted to reopen.

Comment: So add the missing `<audio id="localAudio">` element. or change window.localAudio to the id of your audio element or change it to use document.querySelector or document.getElementById. The description text below the code in the tutorial explains what it is. The answer is copying info from the dupe and copying text from the tutorial.

Comment: @SebastianSimon would you like to add it as an answer?

Comment: @epascarello yup, I figured.

Comment: @epascarello it was really poorly worded in the tutorial, I actually didn't understand it. "sets the <audio> element with the ID of localAudio's src attribute to be the MediaStreamreturned by the promise so that it will play our stream." - it's either me, or it doesn't sound like having an `<audio>` element with `id="localAudio"`. I thought it creates something behind the scenes.

Comment: @epascarello The answer is giving a description on why things happen (like in these comments). The next person going through this tutorial & getting the exact same error, will maybe not even get to this answer, because it is burried in the comments and the linked dupe is not giving any info on why `localAudio` is not defined.

Comment: That is a horrible tutorial in general. Seems odd that is even on MDN

Comment: So now you know the answer, answer your question. Add the missing tag, change the code so it does not use bad practices when referencing an element. Bonus, alter the tutorial with a PR on github to add clues you need an audio tag.

Comment: @epascarello I'll let Sebastian Simon do that, as he was the one to find the answer first. I'll be happy to reward him.

Comment: Yes, this should really be reported on [MDN’s GitHub](//github.com/mdn/content/issues). I haven’t checked thoroughly, but there may be plagiarism involved in this article. Regarding this question, I’m really not sure what kind of answer or other action best fits here. Feel free to write an answer.

Comment: @SebastianSimon The things you said in the comment (along with the criticism of the article) would be the best fit in my opinion.

Comment: @SebastianSimon it also looks like `window.localStream = stream` doesn't do anything special neither and it probably only used to store the stream object globally.

Answer (score -1):

I will try to give you something more useful than the question you have asked.
The function will create the element if it is not present and there are few options available. In the example I'm adding the newly created audio element to the body, but it will work even it is not added - it's a matter of choice.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var el;

        function attachStream(stream, el, options) {
            var item;
            var URL = window.URL;
            var element = el;
            var opts = {
                autoplay: true,
                mirror: false,
                muted: false,
                audio: false,
                disableContextMenu: false
            };

            if (options) {
                for (item in options) {
                    opts[item] = options[item];
                }
            }

            if (!element) {
                element = document.createElement(opts.audio ? 'audio' : 'video');
            } else if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'audio') {
                opts.audio = true;
            }

            if (opts.autoplay) element.autoplay = 'autoplay';
            if (opts.muted) element.muted = true;
            if (!opts.audio && opts.mirror) {
                ['', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o', 'ms'].forEach(function(prefix) {
                    var styleName = prefix ? prefix + 'Transform' : 'transform';
                    element.style[styleName] = 'scaleX(-1)';
                });
            }

            element.srcObject = stream;
            return element;
        };

        function getLocalStream() {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: false,
                audio: true
            }).then(
                stream => {
                    var doesnotexist = !el;
                    el = attachStream(stream, el, {
                        audio: true,
                        autoplay: true
                    });
                    if (doesnotexist) document.body.appendChild(el);
                }
            ).catch(err => {
                console.log("u got an error:" + err)
            });
        }

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            getLocalStream();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `window` is an object and the `window.localStream` is simply creating a new property on the `window` object.

Comment: The question is about `localAudio`, not `localStream`.